# Get the subtrees of an ast

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a boolean abstract syntax tree

```
type bast =
    True
  | False
  | Not of bast 
  | Or of bast * bast 
  | And of bast * bast
```

and I want to apply on it a function and get all the subtrees that return true for this function.

My try:

```
let findtrees f (ast: bast ) =
    let rec findtree (tree: bast ) (mylist: bast list) = match tree with
        | True ->
            if (f tree)=true then mylist@[tree] else []
        | False ->
            if (f tree)=true then mylist@[tree] else []
        | Not e     ->  Not (findtree e subtrees)
        | And (e1,e2) ->  And (findtree e1 mylist, findtree e2 mylist)
        | Or  (e1,e2) ->  Or  (findtree e1 mylist, findtree e2 mylist)
    in findtree ast []
```

I get an error:

> Error: The variant type list has no constructor Not

Tried also with this:

```
let findtrees f (ast: bast) =
    let rec findtree (tree: bast) (mylist: bast list) = match tree with
          (True|False) -> mylist
        | subtree ->
            if (f subtree)=true then
                mylist@[subtree]
            else
                select_tree subtree mylist
    in findtree ast []
```

Compiles fine but never terminates!

Comment: try using `| Not(e) -> Not(findtree e subtrees)`

Comment: same error, @ChrisStewart

Comment: you probably want to return `mylist@[Not (findtree e subtrees)]` or more simply `(Not (findtree e subtrees))::mylist` if you don't care about the result ordering. Same goes for `And` and `Or` in the next matches.

Comment: neither of them works, @didierc

Comment: Let's clarify the goal of your function: you want to go through every subtree of a given tree (including subtrees of subtrees) and return all those accepted by the given function `f`, is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

first of all, it shouldn't compile, since `Bast` should be lowercased.

That is because you return a value of type `list` on first two cases, and an atom on a latter three. Moreover, (compiler didn't mentioned it yet, but will soon) `Not` constructor accepts a `bast`, but you're trying to create it with a `bast list`

Comment: Thanks for the help, @ivg ! any suggestion on this?

Comment: You need to make sure the return type is the same on all branches of the function. You can't return something of type `list` and of type `bast` in the same function in Ocaml as you can in a dynamically typed language such as python. Do you want your function to return a `bast` or a `list`?

Comment: I want to return a list of all the subtrees for which f argument returns true.

Comment: I think, that you confused yourself and trying to do wrong things. First off all, if your function `f` already accepts `bast` then it should recurse into the tree. That means, that you have indeed two nested loops. Also, the task looks wrong to me. I think, that you're trying to do something similar to that https://github.com/ivg/where/blob/master/where.ml. But I may be wrong. I would suggest you, to start with an examples, of how your function should work. Like given this input, I expect this output.

Comment: Problem is that when I return a bast type on leaves ( if f tree then tree) there's no else condition as my ast doesnt support empty values. therefore I return the list.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to do something that is logically incorrect and implausible.

Comment: What I want to do is to write a function that takes another function and a syntax tree, and returns a list of all the subtrees for which the first argument returns true. Why is this logically incorrect? 
I know my implementation is not correct...but the logic makes sense (imo)

Comment: I've already gave you a suggestion, to start from test cases. I hope, that afterwards you will understand, that you're on a wrong way.

Comment: Sorry, but cannot see really what you suggest. could u make it clearer?

Comment: how are you going to use your function, can you create examples? Like if I have the following function `f` and input `x`, I'm expecting to get the output `y`. Also, try to figure out, what you are really trying to do. For example, try to think about function `f`, what it should do. Try to start from writing simple `f` functions.

Comment: Found the solution finally. But I'm getting back the whole ast and not a subtree of it. Maybe that's what u were saying that there's no logic ?!

Comment: pretty close, but not really.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would probably write as a first working attempt:

```
let findtrees f (ast: bast ) =
  let rec findtree tree mylist = 
    let mylist = if f tree then tree::mylist else mylist in
    match tree with
      | True| False -> mylist
      | Not e -> findtree e mylist
      | Or (e1,e2)
      | And (e1,e2) ->  findtree e2 @@ findtree e1 mylist
  in findtree ast []
```

Some remarks:

- You don't need to write `exp = true` for any expression `exp` (in your case it was `f tree`), since it implies that that `exp` is of type `boolean` and the resulting value would be exactly the same (please write the truth table to verify that)
- I replaced `mylist@[tree]` with `tree::mylist` which is faster, but will produce a list in reverse order. If you care about that order, and wish to have the latest tested tree at the end of the list, simply apply `List.rev` to the result (you may of course include that in the body of `findtrees`)
- Because your tree represents boolean expressions, there's perhaps a better way of handling the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you for your help @didierc. 
That's quite close to what I want. 

Do you mean  findtree e2 mylist @ findtree e1 mylist instead of
findtree e2 @@ findtree e1 mylist ?

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I wrote, but for versions of ocaml previous to 4.00 you probably want to replace that with `findtree e2  (findtree e1 mylist)`.